# How I can include bower for my theme?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, frontend

I want to include bootstrap and font-awesome for my theme.
Currently I have:
*app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[MyTheme]/.bowerrc*

```
{
    "directory" : "web/bower"
}
```

*app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[MyTheme]/web/bower/bootstrap/...*
*app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[MyTheme]/web/bower/font-awesome/...*

Command setup:static-content:deploy not working with this.

I think it's wrong way. How to put the bower correctly?

Comment: Please add more details about your question: the folder structure, what you done?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I added more info.

Comment: Have you imported Bootstrap and Font Awesome via Less/Scss?

Comment: @Ben-Space48 No, I don't want to use less. My page layout also does not use less.